# Using Preset Filters From CamanJS API

Tags: javascript, html, camanjs

I am using CamanJS plugin to apply effects to images, I want to know how do I apply preset effects like lomo, sin city, cross process, etc found [here](http://camanjs.com/examples/). The documentation of CamanJS does not  elaborate on this properly.

I tried the below code to apply vignette effect , but was not successful.

```
Caman("#effects", function () {

        this.resize({width: 650,height: 400
         });
         this.vignette();
        this.render();

            });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vignette filter requires a size in order to work. It can either be an absolute number or a percentage.

```
this.vignette(400);
this.vignette("10%");
```

It also takes an optional strength parameter whose range is 0-100.

```
this.vignette("10%", 40);
```

You're right though, all of the filters should be documented better.